# Heat equation in polar co-ordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I was studying the heat equation, when i saw a new variant of it.
Here's the statement: "the edge $r=a$ of a circular plate is kept at temperature $f(\theta)$. The plate is insulted so that there is no loss of heat from either surface. Find the temperature distribution in steady state"
i am trying to solve it by separating the variables ($r$ and $\theta$) from the polar heat equation, however the separation is not going as expected on lines analogous to Cartesian equation. Can someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For simplicity, let's suppose that your disk is the *unit* disk.  The heat equation is $u_t = k\Delta u$. Steady state means that the temperature $u$ does not change; thus $u_t=0$ and you are left with Laplace's equation: $\Delta u=0$ subject to $u(1,\theta)=f(\theta)$. The solution may then be written:

$$u(r,\theta )=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } r^n\left(a_n\cos (n \theta )+b_n\sin (n \theta )\right),$$

where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$, as justified below.  Alternatively, the $a_n$s and $b_n$s may be replaced with their integral representations, the order of summation and integration may be flipped, and (after a lot of simplification) this morphs into an integral representation the Poisson integral formula:

$$u(r,\theta )=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }f(\phi )\frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2+r^2-2R r \cos (\theta -\phi )}d\phi.$$

This is particularly nice for numerical computation.

**An example**

As a cute example, suppose that $f(\theta )=\sin (2\theta )$. Then, $f$ is already a very short Fourier series and the solution is $u(r,\theta )=r^2\sin (2\theta )$.  This looks something like so:

[image]

Note that $\sin(2\theta)$ meanders up and down on the boundary and the solution obeys many of the properties that we expect from a steady state solution.  In particular, the Maximum Principle is satisfied.  This is probably how the [Pringle](http://img.ehowcdn.com/article-new/ehow/images/a07/6s/hh/mail-pringle-chip-breaking-800x800.jpg) was discovered.

**Separation of variables**

Here is the outline of the separation of variables required to derive the Fourier series representation.  We start with the polar specification of the problem.

$$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta }=0,\text{  }u(1,\theta )=f(\theta ).$$

Setting $u(r,\theta )=R(r)\Theta (\theta )$, the PDE becomes

$$R^{\prime\prime }\Theta +\frac{1}{r}R'\Theta +\frac{1}{r^2}R\, \Theta ^{\prime\prime }=0$$

which separates into

$$-\frac{r^2R^{\prime\prime }+r\, R'}{R}=\frac{\Theta ^{\prime\prime }}{\Theta }=-\lambda$$

leading to the two ODEs

$$r^2R^{\prime\prime }+r\, R'=\lambda \, R\text{   }\text{and}\text{  }\Theta ^{\prime\prime }=-\lambda \, \Theta .$$

To find the eigenstructure, we focus on the $\theta$ equation.  First, note that $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue with any constant a representative eigenfunction. Now, implicit in the $\theta$ equation are periodic boundary conditions $\Theta (0)=\Theta (2\pi )$ and $\Theta '(0)=\Theta '(2\pi )$. Furthermore,
the general solution of the $\theta$ equation is

$$\Theta (\theta )=a \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\theta \right) + b \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\theta \right)$$

which has derivative

$$\Theta '(\theta )=-a\sqrt{\lambda } \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\theta \right) + b\sqrt{\lambda } \cos \left(\sqrt{\lambda }\theta \right).$$

Thus, the boundary conditions become

$$a =a \cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right) + b \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)$$

and

$$b\sqrt{\lambda }=-a\sqrt{\lambda } \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right) + b\sqrt{\lambda } \cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right).$$

This is equivalent to the system

$$\left(\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)-1\right)a + \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)b = 0\\
\\
a \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right) + \left(1-\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)\right)b = 0$$

or

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)-1\right) & \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right) \\
 \sin \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)  & \left(1-\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This has a non-trivial solution if and only if the matrix has determinant zero, i.e.

$$\left(\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)-1\right)\left(1-\cos \left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)\right) - \sin ^2\left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)
= 0.$$

Using a few trig identities, this simplifies down to $-4\sin ^2\left(2\pi \sqrt{\lambda }\right)=0$. This implies that $\sqrt{\lambda}$ must be a positive integer or $\lambda =n^2$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Next, we must solve the $r$ equation. Setting $\lambda =n^2$ in the $r$ equation we get

$$r^2R^{\prime\prime }+r\, R'=n^2R.$$

This is called a Cauchy-Euler equation and has general solution $R(r)=c_nr^{-n}+d_nr^n$, which is quite easy to check. Since the solution should
be bounded, we must have $c_n=0$ for all $n$. As a result, we have $R_n(r)=d_nr^n$ and

$$u(r,\theta )=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } r^n\left(a_n\cos (n \theta )+b_n\sin (n \theta )\right).$$

Note that the $a_0$ arises from the zero eigenvalue and that the $d_n$ can be sucked up into the other constants.

Finally, we need to choose the $a_n$s and $b_n$s so that the boundary condition is satisfied, i.e. we want

$$u(1,\theta )=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(a_n\cos (n \theta )+b_n\sin (n \theta )\right) = f(\theta).$$

Thus, the $a_n$s and $b_n$s are just the full Fourier coefficients of $f$ as claimed.

Comment: You get my vote for a very neat explanation :)

Comment: @Pragabhava Thanks!

Comment: awesome explanation! thanks Mark.