# Solving Laplace equation in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I have some assignments to do and I don't even know where to start. The notes in the course aren't too good, so I didn't understand too much from them.

Given $$ \Omega  = \{(x, y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2 , \quad 1 <  x^2 +  y^2  < 4\}$$
and the following problem: 
$$u_{xx}(x,y) + u_{yy}(x,y) = 0 \quad \operatorname{for} \; (x,y) \in \Omega, $$ 
$$u(\cos  \theta , \sin \theta ) = f( \theta ),  \quad \theta  \in [0,2\pi],$$
$$u(2 \cos  \theta , 2 \sin  \theta ) = g( \theta ). $$

a) Given $v(r, \theta ) = u(r \cos  \theta , r \sin  \theta ),$ and that $u$ is the solution of the problem, write the equation satisfied by $v$ and the values of $v(1, \theta)$ and $v(2,\theta ).$

b) In order to get the solution $v,$ we use the method of separation of variables. We shall look for particular solutions of the form $$v(r,\theta) = A_k(r)B_k(\theta)$$ with $r \in [1,2]$ and $ \theta \in [0,2\pi].$ Find the form of the particular solutions.

c) Write the general form of the solution $v.$

I don't expect anyone to do this whole assignment for me, but it would be great if anyone gives me some ideas for what I should do and/or some links as a reference.

Thanks!

Comment: mattebu, i edited your question. can you please check i have not made any changes of your intention. you don't need so many dollar symbols. there is a latex guide you can look up.

Comment: It's good. Thanks! Sorry, I was pretty busy and the guide long, so I went through it fast. :D

Comment: do you know what the laplacian in polar coordinates?

Comment: $\Delta$u = $v_{rr}$ +  $v_r$ / r + $v_{\theta \theta}$ / $r^2$ ?

Comment: not the last comment but the one before is the correct one. now assume $u = R(r)T(\theta)$ substitute in and get two differential equations for $T$ and $R$. you will have to use the periodic boundary conditions to determine the constant.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411158/). That question involves a disk, rather than an annulus - a change that affects the inner boundary condition.  Nonetheless, there are some very similar ideas involved.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. :) I'll try and see what I get.